# Spring rest controller - different values for same header

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have a Spring REST controller and two separate GetMappings with the same value but each accepting a different header value for the same header (i.e., one GET method for v1 and one GET method for v2).

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}",  headers = { "Accept-version=v1"})
public UserV1 findByIdV1(@PathVariable long id) {
  return ...;
}


@GetMapping(value = "/{id}",  headers = { "Accept-version=v2"})
public UserV1 findByIdV2(@PathVariable long id) {
  return ...;
}
```

In case the **implementation does not change from one version to another,** what is the best way to have a single method that can accept either of the header values?

Ideally, the solution would allow me to **have different methods for different versions with different implementations** to be able to properly document these using OpenAPI. Something similar to the following:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}",  headers = { "Accept-version=v1 OR Accept-version=v2"})
public UserV1 findByIdV1(@PathVariable long id) {
  return ...;
}

// Different response, thus need different method to be able to document this.
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}",  headers = { "Accept-version=v3"})
public UserV3 findByIdV2(@PathVariable long id) {
  return ...;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@RequestHeader` to pass the header information inside the method as a parameter:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
public UserV1 findByIdV2(
    @PathVariable long id, 
    @RequestHeader("Accept-version") String acceptVersion
) {
    // make a decision based on acceptVersion
    return ...;
}
```

Comment: I thought about this but I would like to have different methods when versions change in case the response object change - so that I can document it using OpenAPI

Comment: In the question: *"...what is the best way to have a single method..."*. In the comment: *"... I would like to have different methods ..."*. It depends on what do you want.

Comment: You're right, I'll update my question. Need same method for different versions with the same implementation but different methods for versions with different implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it though `Accept` header.

A great example is the Github API: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/overview/media-types

**Spring implementation:**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}", headers = {"Accept=application/vnd.api.v1+json", "Accept=application/vnd.api.v2+json"})
public UserV1 findByIdV1(@PathVariable long id) {
  return ...;
}

@GetMapping(value = "/{id}", headers = "Accept=application/vnd.api.v3+json")
public UserV3 findByIdV2(@PathVariable long id) {
  return ...;
}
```

**Note:** You can change `api` part on your own domain name, the `vnd.` part is dictated by [rfc4288-3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4288#section-3.2) and is used to tell standard media types apart from custom ones.